# Can't save PipelineModel in Spark for Decision Trees

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

While trying to save a model pipeline that comes from a pipeline with one estimator -- a decision tree -- I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Pipeline write will fail on this Pipeline because it contains a stage which does not implement Writable. Non-Writable stage: dtc_c13531497173 of type class org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassificationModel
```

I've seen similar issues for other estimators, are you aware of any fix for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug. It is a normal behavior if `PipelineModel` contains a stage which doesn't implement [`MLWritable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLWritable).

How to fix it? Update your Spark installation to 2.0+. See [SPARK-11888](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11888)